# fetching post request don't log success if the request succeed

Tags: javascript, express, error-handling, fetch, http-post

I'm trying to sign up new user, when I'm sending the post request the server register the user well, and I can see them in my data base, but I can't see the success log in my console (I can catch the error and it logs in my console).

Server side code:

```
var express = require("express");
const { Error } = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
var router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/user");
const catchAsync = require("../utils/catchAsync");

router.post(
  "/register",
  catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { email, username, password } = req.body;
      const user = new User({ email, username });
      await User.register(user, password);
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error("Error signing up");
    }
  })
);

module.exports = router;
```

Client side code:

```
  const sumbitHandler = async (data) => {
  const { username, email, password } = data;
  try {
    await fetch("http://localhost:9000/users/register", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username,
        email,
        password,
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res && !res.ok) {
          throw new Error("ERROR");
        }
        console.log("Success");
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e.message);
      });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
};
```

Comment: I don't see any res.json in your server side code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are mixing the `async/await` style and the older `.then()` Promise-style. Choose one or the other (I *strongly* recommend `async/await`)
2. You are not transforming `fetch`'s response into JSON, leaving it in Promise state.
3. Your server is never responding to the client! You need to add `res.end()`, `res.send()`, `res.json()` or something.

```
    const sumbitHandler = async (data) => {
        const { username, email, password } = data;
        try {
    
            const response = await fetch("http://localhost:9000/users/register", {...});
    
            const serverResponse = await response.text(); // or response.json() if your servers sends JSON back
    
            console.log("Success! serverResponse is = ", serverResponse ); // "Done!"
    
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    };
```

Server :

```
...
await User.register(user, password);
res.send("Done!"); // or res.json({ status : "ok" }); etc.
```